# change attr element by javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

This is my HTML Code:

```
<div class="desc">
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,....</p>
<img src="http://sample.com/dl/image-1.jpg">
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,....</p>
<img src="http://sample.com/dl/image-2.jpg">
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,....</p>
<img src="http://sample.com/dl/image-3.jpg">
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,....</p>
<img src="http://sample.com/dl/image-4.jpg">
</div>
```

This is my JavaScript code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.desc img').addClass('thumb lazyload').attr('data-src', $('.desc img').attr('src') ).attr('src','img/ui/logo/lazy.jpg');
});
```

I want the code to be as below, but the JavaScript code does not work:

```
<div class="desc">
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,....</p>
<img class="thumb lazyload" src="img/ui/logo/lazy.jpg" data-src="http://sample.com/dl/image-1.jpg">
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,....</p>
<img class="thumb lazyload" src="img/ui/logo/lazy.jpg" data-src="http://sample.com/dl/image-2.jpg">
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,....</p>
<img class="thumb lazyload" src="img/ui/logo/lazy.jpg" data-src="http://sample.com/dl/image-3.jpg">
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,....</p>
<img class="thumb lazyload" src="img/ui/logo/lazy.jpg" data-src="http://sample.com/dl/image-4.jpg">
</div>
```

Comment: It works as expected for me

Comment: what error are you getting?

Comment: What are you expecting to happen here?  "It does not work" is insufficient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the following.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.desc img').each(function(i, el) {
    $(el).addClass('thumb lazyload').attr({
      'data-src': $(el).attr('src'),
      'src': 'img/ui/logo/lazy.jpg'
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="desc">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,....</p>
  <img src="http://sample.com/dl/image-1.jpg">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,....</p>
  <img src="http://sample.com/dl/image-2.jpg">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,....</p>
  <img src="http://sample.com/dl/image-3.jpg">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,....</p>
  <img src="http://sample.com/dl/image-4.jpg">
</div>
```

This code itereates over each of the selected items and makes the change for each element. Your code is ambiguous and you may not get the results you expected.

See more: https://api.jquery.com/each/

Answer (score 0):

```js
document.querySelector('[src="img/ui/logo/lazy.jpg"]').classList.add([mention classname you want to add]);
```

This is how you can add or remove classname or can change attr

Answer (score 0):

`$('.desc img').attr('src')` returns the attribute of the first element matching the selector, not the element whose `data-src` attribute is being set.

You can give a function as the second argument to `.attr()`. The function will be called with `this` equal to the current element, and its return value will be used for that element.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.desc img').addClass('thumb lazyload').attr('data-src', function() {
    return this.src;
  }).attr('src', 'img/ui/logo/lazy.jpg');
});
```

```html
<div class="desc">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,....</p>
  <img src="http://sample.com/dl/image-1.jpg">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,....</p>
  <img src="http://sample.com/dl/image-2.jpg">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,....</p>
  <img src="http://sample.com/dl/image-3.jpg">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,....</p>
  <img src="http://sample.com/dl/image-4.jpg">
</div>
```